# <video> Not working on Mobile

Tags: lightning-web-components

Hi I have create LWC component for selfie upload, added LWC on flow and created Quick Action for Selfie Upload. Its working as expected in desktop once click on button camera opening and working selfie. But in mobile once click on camera not turn on to take selfie.
HTML:

```
<video class="videoElement" webkit-playsinline="true" autoplay width="320" height="240"> </video>
```

Js:

```
async initCamera() {
        if (navigator.mediaDevices && navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia) {
            try {
                this.videoElement.srcObject = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({video: true, audio: false});
            } catch (error) {
                console.error('Error accessing the camera: ', JSON.stringify(error));
            }
        } else {
            console.error('getUserMedia is not supported in this browser');
        }
    }
```